# Selected attribute change in button (React)

Tags: reactjs

My component has a attribute `Selected` in `<ListItem Button/>`
Okay, but I change this menu and I want to have another selected element when I choose it. How can I transfer this state change to a component? (I'm learning react.js)

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from 'react';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import { Home, Payment, Settings } from '@material-ui/icons/';

export default class Navigation extends Component {
  state = {};

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Divider />
        <List component="nav">
          <ListItem button selected>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Home />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Strona główna" />
          </ListItem>
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Payment />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Moje płatności" />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List component="nav">
          <ListItem button>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <Settings />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Ustawienia" />
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you’re asking here but I think what you are looking for is event listeners and and event handlers. You can use this to change the state in your parent component and pass the state as a prop to the children.